# How to show unlimited Resources in game unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a different number of items and when i drag and drop any of these  items is remove but according to my **test case there should UN Limited resource so if user pick one of them it copy remain there**

here is the example when i pick bear empty container is shown but i want a copy of bear also remains there ?
[image]

**Object in inspector**

[image: Object in inspector]

Here is my Drag and Drop Scrpit

```
float distance = 3;

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
    Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);

    transform.position = objPosition;
}
```

Comment: What i've understand from your code is; you have an object and you pick it, but you move the actual object.The object. What i can suggest is, you should create references. Like in the panel there will be objects(your resources). When you start dragging the object you want, first instantiate a new object and move its position. You can also check if the object from panel which will be instantiated has enough count. if not you will not instantiate it.

Comment: @EmreE yes i want the same  I am Newbie in Unity can 
It will helps me a lot if you reference Some example or some tutorial or guide line , or please tell the name of thing (With reference to unity ) Which can full fill this thing Thanks For your time highly appreciated

Comment: I cannot view the image you linked due to my work firewall, but i assume it is 2d. First check Unity [UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui) if you don't know how to use it. So you can create a panel with your resources inside. You already know how to move the object with drag, so check [instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) . In the end when you click a resource, instantiate the new object, make it follow the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have just the mesh, or "graphics" of the object actually on the shelf. And when the user clicks on the graphics, it creates (instantiates) an new actual object that can then be dragged around. This way every time the user clicks, a new object is created and the fake object on the shelf always stays there.

Edit: just to add, you probably don't want a real object on the shelf because then it may give you problems with collisions etc. When you instantiate the new object in the exact same location.